# Absolute Positioning in Absolute Container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a banner with text on top of it.
Normally I would have absolute content in a relative container, but my current banner is using absolute positioning. 
I tried another relative container to wrap around it but the banner disappears.
Anyone have an idea of how I could have absolute positioning inside a absolute container?

```
  <div class="product-banner">
    <div class="banner-content">
      <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
      <p>LOREM IPSUMLOREM IPSUMLOREM IPSUMLOREM IPSUMLOREM IPSUMLOREM IPSUM</p>
      <button>WATCH VIDEO</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

/***CSS***/

```
.product-banner {
    margin: 7px 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
}

.product-banner img {
  display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.banner-content {
    position: absolute;
  // left: 595px;
  left: 30%;
  top: 220px;
  width: 435px;
}

.re-cont {
position: relative;

}

.banner-content h2 {
  color: #007078;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.banner-content p {
  font-size: 1rem;  
}

.banner-content button {
  background: #6CC049;
  border: none;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 5px 8px;
}

.product-banner  {
  background: black;
  clear: both;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
  max-height: 468px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;

  background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24098368/responsive-hero-bg-1.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  // background-size:cover;

  @media (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 1025px) {
    background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24098368/responsive-hero-bg-2.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    // background-size:cover;
  }

  @media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1500px) {
    background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24098368/responsive-hero-bg-3.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    // background-size:cover;
  }

  @media (min-width: 1500px) {
    background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24098368/responsive-hero-bg-4.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    // background-size:cover;
  }
}

.product-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 443px;
}
```

Comment: What is it about your current solution that's wrong? The text seems to be above the banner. Position absolute within position relative or absolute will work the same (ie position absolute is calculated from closest non-static position element)

Comment: I am using 30%, but when I shrink the browser, it shifts a little bit too much to the left...I want it to stay at a certain location

Comment: I see the issue now - so your positioning is working correctly. But you have .product-banner set to 100% width and its background set to center. So it is no longer covering enough of the div, making it appear as though the text is in the wrong place. You need to either set the background size to 'cover' or set the div to be the size of the image, or use an <img> tag rather than background so that the div scales correctly.

Comment: I'll give it a try, thanks!